# Equivalent of canvas quadraticCurveTo in SVG

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, svg, bezier

I am working on a plugin to allow "natural looking" signatures to be drawn using mouse or touch. When confirmed by the user, the result will be a stored SVG that can then be displayed in place of the "Click to sign" button.

The attached JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/67haj4nt/3/ shows a testbed for what I am trying to do. The SVG generated image should look close to the original canvas paths.

[image]

The first div contains a `canvas`, in which I draw some multiple-segment lines (e.g. paths). Using `quadraticCurveTo`, and a midpoint for the control point, I draw the lines with smooth curves. This works just fine.

The key part of the curved line drawing is:

```
$.each(lines, function () {
    if (this.length > 0) {
        var lastPoint = this[0];
        ctx.moveTo(lastPoint[0], lastPoint[1]);
        for (var i = 1; i < this.length; i++) {
            var point = this[i];
            var midPoint = [(lastPoint[0] + point[0]) / 2, (lastPoint[1] + point[1]) / 2];
            ctx.quadraticCurveTo(lastPoint[0], lastPoint[1], midPoint[0], midPoint[1]);
            lastPoint = point;
        }
        // Draw the last line straight
        ctx.lineTo(lastPoint[0], lastPoint[1]);
    }
});
```

I have tried multiple options for SVG generation of the same output, but I am stumped on how to convert the same sets of points to equivalent curved lines. Quadratic Beziers require "proper" control points, but I would prefer to use the far simpler *mid-points* if possible.

Any ideas? Is this possible or will I have to convert both to use Beziers with calculated control point(s). Is there a simple way to calculate control points that will do the same job?

*jQuery or raw JavaScript solutions are fine, but you need to demonstrate in the JSFiddle provided* :)

Comment: Just curious. The way you are using quadratic curves (with the control point at the midpoint of the line) will just produce a straight line. It sort of defeats the point of using a curve.

Comment: My point is correct. When the control point is at the exact midpoint of two points, the quadratic bezier will be a straight line. See: http://jsfiddle.net/5bjbu3px/  However I now see that you are using different coords in your canvas version to what you are using in the SVG version.  In the canvas version you are drawing through the midpoints and using the array points as control points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a bug in your code.  You are not updating `lastPoint` in your SVG version.

http://jsfiddle.net/67haj4nt/4/

And if you update the SVG version to match the canvas version, you get identical curves.

http://jsfiddle.net/67haj4nt/5/

Comment: Well spotted. Must have messed up on the cut/paste. Thanks.

Comment: I just noticed the SVG is not drawing the full lines. Both ends are shorter on each path than the canvas version. Adding the missing segments.

Comment: After adding the missing end-segments, I notice the lines stop before the end point: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/67haj4nt/6/ Is that an SVG feature (not including the final pixel of lines) or is the canvas version overdrawing?

Comment: I imagine it will be because of the ending `lineTo()` which is in the canvas version, but not the SVG version.

Comment: Thanks, but sorry, how is that different from the link I gave you? The last line in each path appears to come up one pixel shorter. Is that because SVG lines are not inclusive of the end point/pixel?

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice your new link.  The difference is because you were setting a round linecap on your Canvas version, but not on your SVG version. http://jsfiddle.net/67haj4nt/8/

Comment: I really need to learn SVG from the ground up first :) +1 for that extra little detail. They are almost a perfect match now. I don't suppose SVG supports anti-aliasing? (the lines are more aliased on the SVG)

Comment: SVGs are antialiased. The amount of aliasing looks pretty much the same to me,. But it will depend on the browser I guess.

Comment: The difference is subtle, but the canvas drawn versions are slightly blurrier (preferable) compared to the SVG on all browsers we try. Cheers

Comment: For those who do not understand what @PaulLeBeau means by `lastPoint`, he's talking about the use of `midPoint` in `ctx.quadraticCurveTo` is replaced with `lastPoint` in the SVG counterpart